# Passing notifications received from webhooks to the application react native

Tags: react-native, server, axios, webhooks, ngrok

I am using webhooks and ngrok with express in react native and I am having a problem with using webhooks.
I want to the application (App.js for example) to be updated whenever a notification is received in the server via webhooks so I can be able to update a flat-list when a certain event occurs.
I know how to receive the webhook in the server but I cannot find a way to pass this information to the application.
What am I missing or I am going in the wrong track, if so what are other options to pass a notification to the application.
I tried the app.post() as with any other API but it did not work.

Thank you in advance.

**Below is the server code**

```
app.post('/webhook', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        console.log("got webhook" + req + "   type: " + req.body.message_type);
        if (req.body.message_type === 'credential_offer') {
                    console.log("New Credential Offer");
```

**Below is what I tried in the application**

```
axios.get('/webhook').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    const data=  fetchCredentials();
     setCredentials(data);
     console.log(credentials)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Express' app.post handles POST requests and axios.get sends GET requests.  To make a POST call to your server from react using axios, use axios.post.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work.
The problem is I need the application to be live, whenever a notification is received I want the application to know so axios.post() won't work except for 1 time only.